# Multiply array of vectors with array of matrices; return array of vectors?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I've got a `numpy` array of row vectors of shape (n,3) and another numpy array of matrices of shape (n,3,3). I would like to multiply each of the n vectors with the corresponding matrix and return an array of shape (n,3) of the resulting vectors.

By now I've been using a for loop to iterate through the n vectors/matrices and do the multiplication item by item.

I would like to know if there's a more numpy-ish way of doing this. A way without the for loop that might even be faster.

//edit 1:

As requested, here's my loopy code (with `n = 10`):

```
    arr_in = np.random.randn(10, 3)
    matrices = np.random.randn(10, 3, 3)

    for i in range(arr_in.shape[0]): # 10 iterations
        arr_out[i] = np.asarray(np.dot(arr_in[i], matrices[i]))
```

Comment: Share your loopy code?

Comment: I will, just give me a sec...

Comment: With the edited code, the output seems would be `(n,3,3)` and not `(n,3).`

Comment: Uh, yes, I see... wait a moment... I'll correct the code. Strange thing is: this simplified example works in a development environment exactly as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `dot-product` is essentially performing reduction along `axis=1` of the two input arrays. The dimensions could be represented like so -

```
arr_in   :     n   3 
matrices : n   3   3
```

So, one way to solve it would be to "push" the dimensions of `arr_in` to front by one `axis/dimension`, thus creating a singleton dimension at `axis=2` in a 3D array version of it. Then, sum-reducing the elements along `axis = 1` would give us the desired output. Let's show it -

```
arr_in   : n   [3]   1 
matrices : n   [3]   3
```

Now, this could be achieved through two ways.

1) With [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik',arr_in,matrices)
```

2) With [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(arr_in[...,None]*matrices).sum(1)
```

Runtime test and verify output (for `einsum` version)  -

```
In [329]: def loop_based(arr_in,matrices):
     ...:     arr_out = np.zeros((arr_in.shape[0], 3))
     ...:     for i in range(arr_in.shape[0]):
     ...:         arr_out[i] =  np.dot(arr_in[i], matrices[i])
     ...:     return arr_out
     ...: 
     ...: def einsum_based(arr_in,matrices):
     ...:     return np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik',arr_in,matrices)
     ...: 

In [330]: # Inputs
     ...: N = 16935
     ...: arr_in = np.random.randn(N, 3)
     ...: matrices = np.random.randn(N, 3, 3)
     ...: 

In [331]: np.allclose(einsum_based(arr_in,matrices),loop_based(arr_in,matrices))
Out[331]: True

In [332]: %timeit loop_based(arr_in,matrices)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.1 ms per loop

In [333]: %timeit einsum_based(arr_in,matrices)
1000 loops, best of 3: 714 µs per loop
```

Comment: This gives the transpose. I.e. `matrix[i].T.dot(arr_in[i])`, rather than `matrix[i].dot(arr_in[i])`. Depends what the OP wants, I guess.

Comment: I need the untransposed multiplication.

Comment: The `np.einsum` suggestion works like a charm, however isn't much faster than a for loop. Anyway, I think I'll stick with it. Thanks!

Comment: @HendrikWiese What are the input array shapes of your actual use case?

Comment: In one case for instance it's (16935, 3) (and the corresponding matrices: (16935, 3, 3))

Comment: @HendrikWiese Not sure if I can agree with you on that. Added runtime tests. Check those out please.

Comment: @Bill Don't think I follow you. Added output verification codes. Check again?

Comment: @Divakar The OP's original code was ambiguous as to whether `M.dot(v)` was being calculated, or `v.dot(M)` (equivalently `M.T.dot(v)`). I assumed the former. When he edited, it became clear he wanted the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). To get `v.dot(M)` for each vector-matrix pair, use `np.einsum("...i,...ij", arr_in, matrices)`. To get `M.dot(v)` use `np.einsum("...ij,...i", matrices, arr_in)`

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot.